# How to install git on AWS EC2 instance

Tags: linux, ubuntu, git, sudo, amazon-web-services

I'm trying to follow [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fLxT1VbBd1U) to install git on an EC2 instance. The tutorial I am following asks to create a new user to install git. Unfortunately, I am not able to execute sudo commands. When run `ls -l $(which sudo)`, I get `---s--x--x 1 ec2-user root 123856 Mar 12 21:08 /usr/bin/sudo`.

When I try changing the ownership of the `/usr` folder via `chown root:root /usr/bin`, I get the message `chown: changing ownership of ‘/usr/bin’: Operation not permitted`. Other attempts to change the ownership via `chmod 400 /usr` didn't work, neither did  `sudo chown -R /usr`, the latter produced the error `"sudo: effective uid is not 0, is sudo installed setuid root?"` which is the same error I got when I tried running `sudo su`. When I try just `su`, I need to enter a password, and I'm not sure what it is.

To actually install git, I am using `yum install git` which needs root access privileges.

Is there any way to install git without sudo privileges? Or otherwise, If there are any EC2 instances that come with git, kindly let me know.

Comment: I assume you are the owner of this EC2 instance?  How is it possible you don't have root permissions on your own EC2 instance?

Comment: That confuses me as well... What can I do to verify / assert ownership?

Comment: I assume just nuking the instance out of orbit is out of the question?  You either need to have control over `ec2-user` or `root`, if you are unable to ssh as root, you would need access to a user with sudo rights.  **By the way you don't want to switch ownership of `/usr/bin` that is a horrible idea.** You really need to ask somebody what the password is.